# Change the fiber of a fibration

Tags: fibration, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $F \rightarrow E \rightarrow B$ be a (Serre) fibration of topological spaces. Given a map $F' \rightarrow F$, is there a criterion for the existence or even an explicit construction of a fibration $E' \rightarrow B$ having $F'$ as the fiber (over some fixed $b \in B$, and the given morphism $F' \rightarrow F$ obtained by pullback of some map $E' \rightarrow E$)?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the map $E'\to E$ to be fiber-preserving?

Comment: In the case where $F'$ is a single point, you are essentially asking whether the fibration $E\to B$ has a section.  It must be possible to set up a kind of obstruction theory for that, but I don't think it would be very tractable in general.  If you have a particular fibration in mind, you will probably need to find an approach tailored to that case.

Comment: @Neil: As written, in the case when $F'$ is a point the question asks for a map $B\to E$ which meets the fiber over $b$ in exactly one point. This is weaker than having a section, I think. If the map $E\to E'$ is supposed to be fiber-preserving, then your observation shows that the explicit construction is not available, in general.